How do I fix this clipping issue with mui minimals text field label?
I'm using mui and minimals to make a text input for a user to add an option to a list used elsewhere, but the label on the TextField is clipping into the outline when focused and I'm not sure why.
Image showing TextField outline clipping into last letter of label
<TextField
    margin={"dense"}
    label={"Add New Option to the Menu"}
    sx={{ width: "100%" }}
    autoFocus
/>

Ideally, there would be an equal gap between the text and outline on both sides. I am not sure how to change the label or outline in minimals so have no idea where to start when fixing
